# How to enable horizontal scroll on `less` with trackpad?

Tags: macos, terminal, pager, tui, trackpad

I want to use my trackpad in macOS to scroll `less` horizontally. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: ask your question here : https://apple.stackexchange.com

Comment: @Freeman https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/464700/how-to-enable-horizontal-scroll-on-less-with-trackpad